# When are 'created_at' and 'updated_at' set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use the `created_at` and `updated_at` in my `before_create` but they do not appear to be set. Any idea when they are set? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`created_at` attribute is set automatically **after** object is created, `updated_at` -- updates after every updating. So, I guess, you cant use it before creating an object